MT5 and Python Trading Bot
I am relatively new to trading and autonomous trading. I have implemented a trading bot in python (using anaconda navigator and Spyder) where I am using the MetaTrader5 API which is offered.
My bot works perfectly with the MetaQuotes Demo account using the API, but as soon as I want to trade through a broker, then it does not execute the trades.
For now, I can run the bot and execute trades as I wish on the demo account by calling the MT5 API in Python, however the moment I would like to use the same bot (running in Spyder and making the same API calls) through a broker, it doesn't work.
The message the API provides when I try to place the Trade is "Auto-trading disabled by server" but when I check I have enabled everything that should allow me to use my bot on my side (and it works on the MetaDemo account)
Is there something special I have to do to get it to work, or do I have to just write the Python code I have in MQL5 in MetaEditor in order for it to work through a broker?
Any help will be highly appreciated, sorry if this is a trivial question, I am still learning how all of this works.

UPDATE: Is there a way to pass data from my python program to a MQL5 program?
I want to use Python to perform the trade signal generation because I am using libraries such as ta and pandas and tensorflow which I do not want to implement in MQL5.
In my MQL program, I want to request data from the Python program and then just place the trades based on the data I get from the Python program.
Would something like this be possible?

Firstly, you need to check if your consultant provides support for accessing Metatrader 5.
By confirming this information, I was able to fix this problem within Tools, Options and checking the Allow Algorithmic Trading option
[

Hi Pablo, thanks for the help. It turns out that it was a setting on the broker's side which had to be enabled. I contacted my broker and they enabled it and it is working fine now!
